# reload UIWebview in Iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, webview

hi im create 5 webview at runtime.I Want to know how i change webview background so that effect is seen directly.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the standard background of a UIWebView, but you could load in a custom html page with a set background color